# Pointer not getting updated after sending to another function

Tags: c, linked-list

I was trying to make a simple Linked List program, also when I'm trying to pop the first element from the list , it's not popping and it still remains the first element in the list, please help me resolve this error.

Here are the required files and the main code.
Thanks.

[stack.c](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJUQ2E4QmNqZ2s4SHc)
[stack.h](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJURXdTcUM3WmNTTjQ)

```
char pop(stack *s){
    if(s == NULL){
        isEmpty(s);
        return -1;
    }
    char x=s->value;
    s=(s->next);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Please try and reduce your code to just the *relevant* problem (i.e., not the full main problem), and include the (relevant) code from your linked files as well. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that you never initialize `s` to `NULL` at the top of your program. That may be an issue.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Can you show the code of `getsize` function from the stack.c file?

Comment: Initializing s to NULL created a segmentation fault on calling the push fuction

Comment: I've added the stack.c code

Comment: note : C is call by value.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand

Comment: `void create(stack *s){
if(s == NULL){
    s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack)*1);` : The caller's `s` is not updated in `create`.

Comment: [sample code of call by value](http://ideone.com/yS19mC)

Comment: Why? s is a pointer here, it should be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is at the following line in your `getsize` function:

`while( (temp->next) != NULL){`

Here `temp` is a pointer which is initialized with the value of the other pointer `s`. (temp and s point to the same address). However you have not allocated any memory to `s` before passing it to `getsize`. So accessing `next` member results in seg fault.

**Solution**:

Before giving the user the choice to manipulate your `stack`, initialize sufficient memory. There is a `create` function in stack.c that allocates memory to your stack. But you are not even calling that function. So to fix your error, simply call `create` at the beginning of your program.

Also, you should not include a `.c` file. You should include the header file *.h instead. (As a good practice).

Comment: It didn't work, i think the problem is in the Create function , someone is telling that it's a call by value function, but it is a pointer so how it can be call by value, please tell me how to resolve if you got the problem